# Create Kubernetes Persistent Volume with mounted directory

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, mounted-volumes

In my `/mnt/` I have a number of hard drives mounted (e.g. at `/mnt/hdd1/`, `/mnt/hdd2/`). Is there any way to make a K8s Persistent Volume on `/mnt` that can see the content of the hard drives mounted under `/mnt`? When I make a Local Persistent Volume on `/mnt`, the K8s pods see the directories hdd1 and hdd2, but they appear as empty.

The following is what I have tested:

#### Undesired solution 1:

I can make a Local Persistent Volume on `/mnt/hdd1` and then my K8s pod will be able to see the contents of hdd1 hard drive. But as I mentioned before, I want my pod to see **all** the hard drives and I don't want to make a persistent volume for each hard drive especially when I mount a new hard drive under `/mnt`.

#### Undesired solution 2:

I can mount a Local Persistent Volume on `/mnt/` with the K8s option of `mountPropagation: HostToContainer` in the yaml file for my deployment. In this case my pod will see the content of the hard drive if I **remount** the hard drive. But this is not desired because if the pod restarts,  I need to remount the hard drive again for the pod to see its content! (Only works when hard drive is remounted when the pod is alive)

Comment: Hi there. In Kubernetes land pods are considered cattle. We try to design things so that a pod can arbitrarily restart and its not a big deal. Silly question: have you considered ignoring the PersistentVolume stuff and just mount a hostPath to the pod https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to mount both hdds directly in a `Pod` ? Local volume gives you such possibility. It's not like a `hostpath` where you can only mount a specific directory on the host. This way you avoid an additional abstraction layer. It's quite interesting finding but unfortunatelly I'm not able to tell you what mechanism prevents the content of `hdd1` and `hdd2` subdirectories to be when `/mnt` is mounted to the `Pod`. But if it works this way, it could be difficult to find a satisfying workaround. Have you tried with `hostpath` ? Same effect ?

Comment: And when it comes to **remount**, could you elaborate a bit more on that ?

Comment: @JustinTamblyn thanks for the reply. I initially didn't like the hostpath because in my current configuration I have deployments rather than pods, and according to K8s references I can't have hostpath in deployment definition. I just checked and realized that I can actually have "hostpath" under PersistentVolume! So basically I renamed "local" in my PersistentVolume definition to "hostPath" and it works and I can see the content of the hard drives in the pods now! I also use nodeSelector to make sure my pod will only run on the server which has the hard drives mounted.

Comment: @mario, thank you, too, for your response. I had been mounting each hdd separately to the pod until I found the solution in the previous message. The point is that I have multiple hard drives and I will be mounting and dismounting them all the time, so it is not just two hard drives to mount individually. About the remount, when I selected the `mountPropagation:HostToContainer` option, it would only propagate newly mounted hard-drives to the pod and the hard drives mounted before pod started looked empty.

Comment: @Ali_MM, could you then post the solution with `hostPath` as an answer ? It will be more clearly visible for other users, especially if you mark it as an accepted answer, which clearly shows it solved your problem. Comments may get deleted after some time and it's always more difficult to notice that there's the actual solution somewhere in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to allow the pod to see all hard drives mounted in a directory using hostpath. A PersistentVolume can be defined in hostpath "mode." My final solution was:

1. Most important part of the solution: **Define a PersistentVolume in hostpath "mode,"** with a nodeAffinity to ensure it will only be mounted on the node with the hard drives:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: all-harddrives-pv
spec:
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: all-harddrives-storage
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt      # Where all the hard drives are mounted
    type: Directory
  nodeAffinity:     # Use nodeAffinity to ensure it will only be mounted on the node with harddrives.
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - MyNodeName
```

2. Define a PersistentVolumeClaim that is bound to the above PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: all-harddrives-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: all-harddrives-storage
```

3. Mount it on the Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mycontainername
          image: myimage
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /mnt
              name: all-harddrives-pvc
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: MyNodeName
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to use a Local Persistent Volume. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/ Keep in mind that it's a bad idea to use either of these things in production. By tying your pod to a single node, you're losing a lot of the benefits of running on Kubernetes in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but when I have terabytes of data which need to be offloaded to multiple hard drives connected to a single server, it is best to tie that pod to that same server.

Answer (score 2):

This approach, [Local Persistence Volume Static Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner), suits better with Kubernetes way of working.

It supports metrics, storage lifecycle (eg. cleanup), node/pv affinity, extensible (eg. dynamic ephemeral storage). For example, with [eks-nvme-ssd-provisioner](https://github.com/brunsgaard/eks-nvme-ssd-provisioner), there can be a daemonset running to provision fast storage as local. This is ideal for workload that requires ephemeral local storage for data cache, fast compute, while no need to manually perform mount on the ec2 node before pods start.

Usage yaml examples are here, [sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/tree/master/examples).